# Celery: check if a task has completed without storing the results

Tags: python, celery

I would like to know when some tasks have finished executing, something I can achieve in celery with:

```
task.ready()
```

I really don't care about the actual results, I only need to know if the task are completed.
Storing the results is not an option, because they are complex objects from an external library, and they are not serializable.

So, is it possible to know when a task is ready, without having to store the results?

Comment: can inspecting the task queues be an option ? By using 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.3/reference/celery.task.control.html#id1
by polling class `celery.task.control.Inspect` with method `active()` or `scheduled()`

Comment: Yeh but it feels like such a hack... :)

Comment: wait, ready() doesnt return result so why cant you just use ready() to know if a task is completed?